# Não consigo usar funções e buscar atributo de classe de um objeto

Tags: python

Não estou conseguindo chamar os atributos dos objetos que crio pela função create_character e nem ativar as funções pertencente a classe. acho que quando tento atribuir o objeto na lista characterList ele está perdendo algumas propriedades pois nem consigo chama .name dele. alguém conseguiria me ajudar pra ver o que esta errado ou faltando?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass,fields,MISSING




characterList = [""]

@dataclass
class character:
    name : str
    genre : str
    race : str
    health : int = 0
    recoveryRate : int = 0
    strength : int = 0
    agility : int = 0
    intellect : int = 0
    will : int = 0
    perception : int = 0
    defense : int = 0
    size : int = 0
    movement : int = 0
    level : int = 0
    power : int = 0
    damage : int = 0
    insanity : int = 0
    corruption : int = 0


    def updateByRace(self):
        if self.race == "human":
            self.strength = 10
            self.agility = 10
            self.intellect = 10
            self.will = 10

            self.perception = self.intellect
            self.defens = self.agility
            self.health = self.strength
            self.recoveryRate = (self.health)/4
            self.size = 1
            self.movement = 10


    def __str__(self):
        return(
            'Character Sheet: \n\n'
            f'Name : {self.name} | '
            f'Genre : {self.genre} | '
            f'Race : {self.race} \n'
            f'Level : {self.level} |'
            f'Power : {self.power} \n'
            f'Damage : {self.damage} |'
            f'Health : {self.health} | '
            f'recoveryRate : {self.recoveryRate} \n'
            f'STR : {self.strength} | '
            f'INT : {self.intellect} | '
            f'AGI : {self.agility} | '
            f'Will : {self.will} \n'
            f'Perception : {self.perception} | '
            f'Defense : {self.defense} | '
            f'Movement : {self.movement} | \n'
            f'Size : {self.size} | '
            f'Insanity : {self.insanity} | '
            f'Corruption : {self.corruption} \n'

        )






def create_character():
    print('New character:')
    global chacterList
    info = {}
    s = True
    while s:
        for field in fields(character):
            if field.default == MISSING:
                value = input(f'{field.name}: ')
                info[field.name] = field.type(value)

        characterList.append(character)
        x = input("do you want to add a new character? [y/n]: ")
        if  x != "y" :
            s = False



create_character()
print(characterList)
print(characterList[1].name)
```

Comment: `characterList.append(character)`, você está adicionando a própria classe à lista, você não criou a instância da classe com `info`.

Comment: E ficou bem estranho você iniciar a lista `characterList` com uma *string* vazia. Por que fez isso?

Comment: estava fazendo isso por comodidade de começar no 1, mas só para teste mesmo no fim ia remover pra conseguir percorrer a lista em for exibindo tudo.

Answer (score 2):

O prblema é que no seu código, em nenhum ponto você cria um novo objeto da
classe `character`  -  Você junta as informações dos campos
num dicionário chamado `info`, e ignora esse questionário, e na sua
lista você adiciona a própria classe, e não objetos dessa classe

Modifique o trecho abaixo:

```
  while s:
        for field in fields(character):
            if field.default == MISSING:
                value = input(f'{field.name}: ')
                info[field.name] = field.type(value)

        characterList.append(character)
        x = input("do you want to add a new character? [y/n]: ")
        if  x != "y" :
            s = False
```

Para esse - que inclui a criação de uma nova instância de `character`:

```
  while s:
        info = {} 
        for field in fields(character):
            if field.default == MISSING:
                value = input(f'{field.name}: ')
                info[field.name] = field.type(value)

        new_character = character(**info)

        characterList.append(new_character)
        x = input("do you want to add a new character? [y/n]: ")
        if  x != "y" :
            s = False
```

Comment: antes tava usando o character(**info) mas em return, achava que como ele exibia todo o objeto era um tipo de print, deu certinho agora aqui mt obg mesmo!

Comment: @pydoni No outro código exibia porque o retorno da função era usado como parâmetro da função `print`.